# Using non-created classes in current class

Tags: java, class, oop, workflow

### Scenario

This question may be a question about conventions, but Java might have a built-in way to do this. I'm explaining my problem with a scenario:

We are three people working on a project, and we're all doing different parts, and working on different git branches, all of which will be needed in the end project.

My part of the program runs the TUI (let's call the class `Startmenu`), which requires to run functions from an instance of the `Database` class. In my `switch` cases, I know the future code from the other branch will allow me to simply run `db.printElements()`, as an example.

### Problem

Nevertheless, this is the problem: I cannot define `Database db;` in the class structure, nor can I assign my `Startmenu()` constructor to take a `Database db`  as an input such as `Startmenu(Database db)`, because it does not yet exist.

In practice, how do I solve this issue? Currently, I'm commenting out the parts that require parts of the other code, and replace it with poisoned code instead, as a placeholder. This doesn't seem like the best idea.

I know a solution is to create the `Database` class, with empty functions for those functions I will be needing right now, but this will mess with git instead.

**tl; dr:** How can I prepare my own files to use code that does not yet exist, which will appear "magically" by other people over time?

Comment: your team needs to spec out an API, and put in stubs until everything is finished and ready to go

Comment: Create ***interface*** for db manipulations. Create basic implementation. When DB is ready create an actual implementation and switch one line.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I assume you mean to create interfaces, as suggested by PM 77-1. Otherwise I might have misunderstood you.

Comment: @PM77-1 Do you have a visual example or a link I could read to understand this?

Comment: Google (i.e. search) for "java DAO pattern".

Comment: The DAO patterns seems very nice. In essence, I need my teammate to create the `DatabaseDaoImpl` class for me, which for a mocking state can have empty functions for all the `DatabaseDao` interface functions.

Comment: Or you can create a mocking class yourself. The main thing here: to agree on the contract that interface enforces.

Comment: Plus you will need it for unit testing anyway.

Comment: Go ahead and answer that the best workflow for these scenarios is to create and use interfaces. Sounds like a good plan.

Comment: The best approach for ***absolutely anything of value*** is to program to interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All components in your project should have specified an interface to exchange information across layers and other Java components during the design phase.

You can early commit and share these interfaces, so other colleagues can provide their own testing implementations or mock behaviours.

Comment: So for all classes that will be shared among the code, there should be a `ClassnameInterface` interace as well, which is filled with empty functions until further update. Is there some way of forcing Java to create empty functions for all functions in the implemented interface?

Comment: You can have your dependencies stubbed in your unit tests with Mockito, for example: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/stubbing-and-mocking-with-mockito-2-and-junit